# shell script to extract mail attachments with specific filename

Tags: shell, attachment, mbox

I'm writing a shell script to extract mail attachments from an mbox file

At the moment I use this command: cat mboxfile|formail -des munpack -qf

But I'd like to embed the sender email address in the filename, something like:

user@host_filename.extension

Can you suggest me some tool?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a scripting language with mbox libraries ? e.g. Perl and the [Mail::MBox](http://search.cpan.org/~dcoppit/Mail-Mbox-MessageParser-1.5002/lib/Mail/Mbox/MessageParser/Perl.pm) module. Using a ready made library will likely save you a lot of grief.

Comment: I'd recommend learning a more powerful scripting language. Doesn't have to be Perl - perhaps Ruby/Python etc.? But I appreciate that doesn't help you right now.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

```
cat $MBOX|formail -des ../dumpFile.sh  # split the mbox in many messages

for mail in *  # cycle on every message
do
 echo ===========================
 FROM=$(../extractFrom.sh $mail |tr -d "<"|tr -d ">"|tr -d "/" |sed 's/@/-AT-/'|tr "." "-"|sort|uniq) # get address
 for file in $(munpack $mail |cut -f1 -d" "|tr -s "_" "-")  # extract attachments and prepend address
 do
  echo ln $file utente:${FROM}_tipo:$file # whatever
 done
done
```

where dumpFile.sh is just:

```
cat >$(mktemp -p .)
```

and extractFrom.sh is an awk script to get the email address

Answer (score 0):

instead of using formail you can also use
munpack with awk to save all attachments of an mbox file:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\r\n";} /^From / { cmd="munpack";  print mail | cmd ;close(cmd) ;mail ="";} {mail = mail $0 "\n";}'
```

if you change the cmd to munpack -C your_destination_dir

after that run this in the directory where your attachmenets are saved:

```
 find . -type f -not -name "your_specific_file" -maxdepth 1 -exec rm {}
```

this removes all the files inside the directory that doesn't match your specific request